# What is a working sequence of import scss in bootstrap 5.2?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make use of particular scss bootstrap 5.2 files instead of importing the entire bootstrap.css

However I am running in to various of issues for which I do not find any solution online.

## These do not work:

> ### Function not found: to-rgb

#### 1.

```
@import '/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

or

```
@import '/node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

#### 2.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

> ### Undefined variable: "$gutters"

#### 3.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

#### 4.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
```

#### 5.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_nav';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_navbar';
```

## These work:

#### 1.

Although I do not want to include all bootstrap

```
@import "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

#### 2.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

#### 3.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
```

#### 4.

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_nav';
@import 'bootstrap/scss/_navbar';
```

However those that work are not enough. I need to include gris and probably some other partials as well.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a guide on importing partials:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/#importing

```scss
// Custom.scss
// Option B: Include parts of Bootstrap

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

// 4. Include any default map overrides here

// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";

// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/helpers";

// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map in `_utilities.scss`
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";

// 8. Add additional custom code here
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to follow. After all, I found out that the issue was with the sass-loader and compilation, not the bootstrap itself. It prvented the functions being included when compiling for some reason.